# how to add class to parent label of the checked radio buttons on the page, once refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Each radio button is inside a label in my html markup. I cannot change the markup. I used the following JavaScript code to add event listener. But when I refresh the page, the radio buttons are still checked but the parent element doesn't have that class anymore because the event listener will again add the class to the parent label when I click it again. How to select all the checked radio button's parents once the page reloads to add the class again.

```
let form = document.querySelector( "form" );
form.addEventListener( "click", ( evt ) => {
  let trg = evt.target,
      trg_par = trg.parentElement;
  if ( trg.type === "radio" && trg_par && trg_par.tagName.toLowerCase() === "label" ) {
    let prior = form.querySelector( 'label.checked input[name="' + trg.name + '"]' );
    if ( prior ) {
      prior.parentElement.classList.remove( "checked" );
    }
    trg_par.classList.add( "checked" );
  }
}, false );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have not shared your complete code, I have replicated the HTML in my way.

You can open the commented code in your application.

tags can be modified as per your HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <label>
Radio 1: <input type="radio" name="rdo" value="1" class="rdo"/>
</label>
  <label>
Radio 2: <input type="radio" name="rdo" checked="checked" value="2" class="rdo"/>
</label>

  <script>
    radio = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var trv = 0; trv < radio.length; trv++) {
      if (radio[trv].checked) {
        let trg = radio[trv],
          trg_par = trg.parentElement;
        if (trg.type === "radio" && trg_par && trg_par.tagName.toLowerCase() === "label") {
          console.log(trg);
          /*let prior = form.querySelector( 'label.checked input[name="' + trg.name + '"]' );
          if ( prior ) {
            prior.parentElement.classList.remove( "checked" );
          }*/
          trg_par.classList.add("checked");
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```